# How to solve this spherical trigonometry situation with missing information?

Tags: trigonometry, spherical-trigonometry

[image: Spherical triangle solved by the law of cosines.]

Suppose $b$ and $c$ were given constants. If $C = \theta - y$ (where $\theta$ is given) and $a = 90 \deg - y $, is it possible to solve for $y$? It seems like there must be a solution, since $y$ can't just be any arbitrary value or else the triangle won't be valid.

So far I have used cosine law for spherical surfaces:

$sin(a) = cos(b)cos(c) + sin(b)sin(c)cos(A)$

$cos(y) = cos(b)cos(c) + sin(b)sin(c)cos(A)$

and sine law:

$ \frac{sin(B)}{cos(b)} = \frac{sin(\theta - y)}{sin(c)} = \frac{sin(A)}{sin(a)} $

$ \frac{sin(B)}{cos(b)} = \frac{sin(\theta - y)}{sin(c)} = \frac{sin(A)}{cos(y)} $

But I can't get it to an expression of $y$. I also cannot think of a way to solve this even if this was a non-spherical trigonometry problem.

Comment: What would the constraint $a = 90^\circ - y$ become in the planar geometry case?  In that case, $a$ would be a distance and $y$ would be an angle, so that equation doesn't immediately make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's not a nice solution to this system.  But briefly, we have
$$
\sin y = \cos b \cos c + \sin b \sin c \cos A
$$
(note that you didn't quite apply the law of cosines right) and
$$
\sin A = \frac{\sin(\theta - y) \cos y}{\sin c}.
$$
But since $\cos A = \pm \sqrt{1 - \sin^2 A}$, we can combine these equations to yield
$$
\sin y = \cos b \cos c + \sin b \sqrt{ \sin^2 c - \sin^2(\theta - y) \cos^2 y}.
$$
This equation implicitly defines $y$.  For any given values of $b$ and $c$, you could plot both sides and see where they intersect to find $y$.

In principle, you could also rearrange this last equation, square both sides a couple of times, and repeatedly use the identities $\cos^2 y = 1 - \sin^2 y$ to reduce this to a polynomial in $\cos y$ or $\sin y$.  However, it looks to me that this polynomial will be of fairly high order, meaning that it's unlikely to have a nice closed-form solution if it has one at all.

Comment: What if we use cosine law on a different part of the triangle? Such as $cos(c) = sin(y)cos(b) + cos(y)sin(b)cos(\theta - y)$. Although this in particular does not obviously simplify. A closed-form solution would be ideal since I'd have to calculate this for thousands of points in a program.